# What is the point in the total differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The total differential is found by taking the limit of 
$$\Delta f \approx f_x \Delta x+ f_y \Delta y$$
as $\Delta x, \Delta y \rightarrow 0$ to give
$$df=f_x dx +f_y dy$$
Is this equation not just saying that $$0=f_x. 0 +f_y.0$$

If not please can you explain why not?

Comment: Do you have the same question regarding $\mathrm dy = \dfrac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\mathrm \Delta x$ as $\Delta x \to 0$?

Comment: @GFauxPas yes I do

Comment: The whole point of differentiation is to take the QUOTIENT of a small change in a function and a small change in a variable. Whereas both these changes can be considered arbitrarily small, their QUOTIENT approaches a CONSTANT VALUE. That is the key point.

Comment: I have the same question. I realize that for functions with a jump, df can come out to the value of the jump, but for continuous functions, wouldn't df always be 0? I never understood total differentials as more than a mnemonic for the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Although both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y\rightarrow 0$, this does not necessarily mean that the product $f_x \Delta x\rightarrow 0$. This is because, the $dx$ or $dy$ in question, are not actually zero, they approach zero but never reach it.

For example:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(x_0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{y(x_0+h)-y(x_0-h)\over 2h}$$

The space between the two $y$'s is never zero, but it heads torwards that while the denominator also heads towards zero! Eventually these find a sort of equilibrium, at $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.